# Calculate result on quiz

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all I am so sorry my bad English. I searching so much document but ı do not understand them due to my English. I designed quiz page but I can not show result end of the page and it have problem an error

I want:

1. if select true section it should give success message,if select false section it should give error message ( it did that)
2. İt should show result how many correct answer ( ı can not do algorithm for this)

I try something but I have so much terrible mistakes.. could you help me HOW MANY QUESTION SELECTED TRUE.

**My code HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <link href="css/boostrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">  
        <link href="css/deneme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="scripts/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>


        <script  type="text/JavaScript" >
            // if they click false section it gives error message
            $(".alerts").on('click', function() {
                var did = $(this).attr('data-id');
                $(document).trigger("set-alert-id-" + did, [
                    {
                        'message': "Wrong",
                        'priority': 'warning'
                    }]);
            });

            // if they click true section it gives success message
            $(".alerts-success").on('click', function() {
                var did = $(this).attr('data-id');
                $(document).trigger("set-alert-id-" + did, [
                    {
                        'message': "Success",
                        'priority': 'warning'
                    }]);
            });

            // I try something to show how many question is true selected but I can not      do this
            function askQuestion(question) {
                var answer = prompt(question[0], '');
                if (answer == question[1]) {
                    alert('Correct!');
                    score++;
                } else {
                    alert('Sorry. The correct answer is ' + question[1]);
                }
            }

            var message = 'You got ' + score;
            message += ' out of ' + questions.length;
            message += ' questions correct.';
            document.write('<p>' + message + '</p>');



        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="quiz_container">
            <ul class="quiz_container" style="padding: 0px;">

                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_0">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who said it: Newt or Schrute?</h1>
                        <p class="text">"Men are basically little piglets...Males are biologically driven to go out and hunt giraffes."</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_0">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0 alerts"  data-id="myid1">Dwight Schrute</li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1"  data-id="myid11"   >Newt Gingrich</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid1" data-fade="3000"></div>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid11" data-fade="3000"></div>


                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_1">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who was it?</h1>
                        <p class="text">He said: "Can we steer away from 'gay people'? I’m sorry, it’s an orientation, not a race. Plus, a lot of other races are intolerant of gays."</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_1">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0 alerts"  data-id="myid2">Must be Schrute</li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1"  data-id="myid2" >Totally Newt</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid2" data-fade="3000"></div>
                <div data-alerts="alerts-success"  data-ids="myid22" data-fade="3000"></div>


                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_2">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who said it?</h1>
                        <p class="text">When he was 11-years-old, he took on City Hall in an attempt to build a zoo from scratch in South Central Pennsylvania.</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_2">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0"  data-ids="myid3" >Lil' Schrute</li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1" data-ids="myid33">Lil' Newt</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid3" data-fade="3000"></div>
                <div data-alerts="alerts-success"  data-ids="myid33" data-fade="3000"></div>

                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_3">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who was it?</h1>
                        <p class="text">This man pitched a radical plan to capture Osama bin Laden using a portable prison that could be operated beyond the pale of traditional covert ops.</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_3">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0"  data-ids="myid4" >Gingrich idea</li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1" data-ids="myid44">Schrute idea</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid4" data-fade="3000"></div>
                <div data-alerts="alerts-success"  data-ids="myid44" data-fade="3000"></div>


                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_4">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who said it?</h1>
                        <p class="text">Publicly referred to pop star Justin Bieber as "Justice Beaver."</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_4">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0" data-ids="myid55" >Dwight gag</li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1"  data-ids="myid5" >Newt gaffe</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid5" data-fade="3000"></div>
                <div data-alerts="alerts-success"  data-ids="myid55" data-fade="3000"></div>

                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_5">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who was it?</h1>
                        <p class="text">When debating the eating habits of T-Rex's, this man explained, "I believe [the T-Rex] was a predator because I saw 'Jurassic Park' and he ate a lawyer and it wasn't a dead lawyer."</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_5">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0">Totally Newt</li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1"  data-ids="myid6" >Definitely Schrute</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid6" data-fade="3000"></div>

                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_6">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who was it?</h1>
                        <p class="text">When thrown a softball question about past "romantic" activities, he mumbled something about "chicken fights."</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_6">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0"  data-ids="myid77" >Dwight Schrute</li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1"  data-ids="myid7" >Newt Gingrich</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid7" data-fade="3000"></div>
                <div data-alerts="alerts-success"  data-ids="myid77" data-fade="3000"></div>



                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_7">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who was it?</h1>
                        <p class="text">He fantasized about ditching the drudgery of the workplace to spend a year in the Amazon, staring at sloths.</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_7">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0" data-ids="myid88">Must be Newt</li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1" data-ids="myid8" >Has to be Schrute</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid8" data-fade="3000"></div>
                <div data-alerts="alerts-success"  data-ids="myid88" data-fade="3000"></div>

                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_8">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who was it?</h1>
                        <p class="text">As recently as 2009, he called the Swedish system of governement and healthcare "communist" and repressive.</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_8">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0" data-ids="myid99">Schrute</li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1"  data-ids="myid9" >Newt</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid9" data-fade="3000"></div>
                <div data-alerts="alerts-success"  data-ids="myid99" data-fade="3000"></div>

                <li class="question_container row-fluid question_9">
                    <div class="question span12 show" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <h1 class="title">Who was it?</h1>
                        <p class="text">His favorite childhood game was curling up into a ball and playing dead on the sidewalk.</p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="span12 possible_answers possible_answers_9">
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_0">
                            Kid Schrute
                            <br>
                            <img  data-ids="myid100" src="../ckeditor/rainn-kid.png">
                        </li>
                        <li class="possible_answer span12 answer_1">
                            Kid Newt
                            <br>
                            <img   data-ids="myid10" src="../ckeditor/newt-kid.png">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div data-alerts="alerts"  data-ids="myid10" data-fade="3000"></div>
                <div data-alerts="alerts-success"  data-ids="myid100" data-fade="3000"></div>

            </ul>

            <p class="how_you_did">
                <span>You got </span>
                <span class="correct_answers">0</span>
                <span> correct answers out of 10 questions</span>
            </p>
            <p class="small">on your first attempt. No fair changing your answers after you found out you were wrong</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.quiz_container {
    list-style-type: none !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #21252E;
    width: 98%;
}

/*fluid grid layout using twitter bootstrap */

.row-fluid {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.span12 {
    padding: .75em;
    margin-top: .75em;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.span12.question {
    padding: 0;
}

/*additional custom styling*/

.quiz_container .question_container {
    margin: 1em 0em 6em;
}

.quiz_container .question_container h1, .question p, .revealed_answer p {
    line-height: 1.5em; 
}

.quiz_container .question_container h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0em 0em 1em 0em;
}

.quiz_container .question p {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    max-height: 8em;
}

.quiz_container .possible_answers.span12 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.quiz_container .possible_answer {
    background: rgba(254, 231, 88, .2);
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 2px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.quiz_container .possible_answer:hover {
    background: rgba(254, 231, 88, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
}

.quiz_container li {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}

/*more styling for answers*/

.quiz_container .revealed_answer p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0em 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 3em;
    font-weight: normal;

}

.quiz_container .revealed_answer a {
    color: #E64522;
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.quiz_container .revealed_answer a:hover {
    opacity: .75;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.quiz_container .correct_answer {
    background: #62DA97;
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.quiz_container .wrong_answer {
    background: #FF8362;    
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.quiz_container .selected {
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;
}

.quiz_container .selected:hover, .correct_answer:hover, .wrong_answer:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.quiz_container .hide {display: none;}

.quiz_container .show {display: block;}

.quiz_container .revealed_answer {
    padding: 0;
}

#quiz_container .how_you_did {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: rgb(254, 231, 88);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
    box-shadow:         0px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
}

/*multimedia styling*/

.quiz_container img, .quiz_container .youtube {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.quiz_container .possible_answer img {
    max-height: 18em;
}

.quiz_container .question img, .revealed_answer img, .selected img, .correct_answer img, .wrong_answer img {
    max-height: 18em;
    display: block;
}

.videoembed {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.videoembed iframe, .videoembed object, .videoembed embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* media queries */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .quiz_container li {
        font-size: 1em !important;
    }

    .quiz_container .question_container h1 {
        font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }

    .quiz_container .question img, .revealed_answer img {
        display: none;
    }

    .quiz_container .question_container {
        margin: 1em 0em 3.5em;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear your are even to the point of calculating the answers. Like you said there are many issues with it right now. I've created a `jsfiddle` here: http://jsfiddle.net/F9vZk/

Comment: yes I searching but I can not do algorithm of calculating answer. İt have to calculate how many true question.. and ı have so much error ı know. :((

Comment: Many issues indeed. I would start to fix them one by one (HTML: no divs allowed in ul, JS: you throw a custom event but never catch it, ...), and ask more specific questions when you get stuck. Now you are basically asking us to write the page for you... And one important piece of advice, add comments to your js, explaining what you expect the code to do! Much easier for us to help, and a lot easier for you if you ever have to change something in the future.

Comment: ok I want to only calculation how many question selected is true.. I can not do this if you choose jquery jsfiddle alert is work. I changed my question ok.

Comment: and I added more information dude

Comment: This is too broad of a task for me to do, I spent 10 minutes trying to clean up your code to make sense of what you are doing. You need to get a better grip of javascript before tackling this. Maybe try this: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Comment: yes I am beginner on javascript as you see my html code. You can give me advice how can I calculate how many question selected true on span.. My english is very bad.. So I do not understand so much english tutorial.. our country has not so much example :(( so I need you

Comment: Have you thought about using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my code at http://jsfiddle.net/LaB92/1/

I removed your css and bootstrap so add your own CSS to it to make it look pretty

coming to the solution

- Every question is wrapped inside "LI - .single_question" `<li class="single_question">`
- .single_question contains the correct answer as attribute -

  `<li class="single_question" data-correct-answer="OPTION VALUE"></li>`
- `data-question-id` is additional attribute (i didn't use it but you may need it later)
- Put your options in `<ul class="options"></ul>`
- Don't forget to add  li value's -  `<li value="OPTION VALUE"> SOME OPTION TEXT </li>`
- Individual result is automatically written to `<div class="result"></div>`. It should be there for every question
- When ever you select an option `score_calculator()` function is called and it calculates the score

Ask me if you didn't understand the code or if you want to extend the functionality a bit. I wrote the basic one ..